# Apollo + React: data not appearing in componentDidMount lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I've got a React app that uses Redux for some in-app state management and Apollo for fetching data from a server.  In my network tab, my graphql queries are succeeding and the response is what I expect, but when I try to reference the data in the componentDidMount lifecycle of the React Component, the data isn't there and the loading state is 'true'.

If I move my code to a different lifecycle function, like render(), the data does appear, but I need it to work in componentDidMount.  I'm new to Apollo.

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import SdkMap from "@boundlessgeo/sdk/components/map";
import SdkZoomControl from "@boundlessgeo/sdk/components/map/zoom-control";

import * as mapActions from "@boundlessgeo/sdk/actions/map";

import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    map: state.map
  };
}

class Map extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const store = this.context.store;
    store.dispatch(mapActions.setView([-95.7129, 37.0902], 3));

    /* ADD SITES LAYER */
    store.dispatch(
      mapActions.addSource("sites_src", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: []
        }
      })
    );

    store.dispatch(
      mapActions.addLayer({
        id: "sites",
        source: "sites_src",
        type: "circle",
        paint: {
          "circle-radius": 3,
          "circle-color": "blue",
          "circle-stroke-color": "white"
        }
      })
    );
    
    console.log(this.props.data);  //response doesn't include query fields
    if (this.props.data.allSites) {
      let sites = this.props.data.allSites.edges;

      for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
        let site = sites[i].node;
        let geojson = site.geojson;
        if (geojson) {
          console.log(site);
          const feature = {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: geojson,
            properties: {
              id: site.id
            }
          };
          store.dispatch(mapActions.addFeatures("sites_src", feature));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const store = this.context.store;

    return (
      <SdkMap store={store} >
        <SdkZoomControl />
      </SdkMap>
    );
  }
}

const query = graphql(
  gql`
    query {
      allSites {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            projectId
            location
            areaAcres
            geojson
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
);

const MapWithRedux = connect(mapStateToProps)(Map);
const MapWithApollo = query(MapWithRedux);

export default MapWithApollo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no need to access `this.context` by yourself. This is an anti-pattern. Always use `connect()`. If you need parts of your state in your component use `mapStateToProps`. If you want to dispatch actions from your component use `mapDispatchToProps` to pass functions into it that do the dispatching for you. This is the second parameter that `connect()` accepts.

Also there is no reason to pass down the store to child components because you can connect every component individually that needs anything from the store.

That being said your problem is that fetching data is asynchronous and your request is probably not completed when `componentDidMount()` is called. So the information that `loading` is true just means, that your fetch did not finish yet. Either you display that to the user by e.g. showing some kind of spinner or you fetch the required data before you render your component.

Comment: Thanks, good advice and I will make those changes.  I'm simply following the redux patterns provided by the authors of Boundless SDK, but looks like there's some improvement to be made there.Yes obviously the async fetch isn't complete by the time componentDidMount() is called, but if i put the stuff from the for loop in the render method, I get an infinite loop of results.

Comment: Putting it in the `render()` method is not the solution. Fetiching your data needs an undefined amount of time depending on external factors you can't always influcence. You need to display something that indicates your component is still loading initial data as long as it's still fetiching. As soon as the data arrive your component will re-render with the data. Or you could provide the initial data yourself and store them in your redux store as initial state.

Comment: Also read up on [prefetching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/prefetching.html) data with `react-apollo`. That might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for trying to walk me through this, but I'm still missing something.  In componentDidMount(), if I console.log(this.props.data.loading), I get 'true'.  Nothing ever happens again though in that lifecycle method, so how do I subscribe to know when it's 'false'?

Comment: Yeah I had that prefetching link open in another tab! I'll take a look

Comment: Yes because as soon as your component mounts it will start your fetching query. But that doesn't mean that it will finish loading until `componentDidMount()` is called. That's why `loading` is still `true`. You need to add something to your render method like `if (this.props.loading) {return <Spinner />}`.

Comment: Not really grasping how adding a conditionally-rendered loading spinner fixes the issue of the query not being available in this.props.data when the component mounts, but I'll try it.

Comment: If you want your data to be already there you need to provide them BEFORE you render your component. How do you expect your data to be magically there before your even fetched it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162761/discussion-between-bramb84-and-trixn).

Comment: can you please provide code that solves this problem? adding a spinner is great but only works in a render method. how are you accessing the data after you have it in the componentDidMount method.

Comment: @bantingGamer I don't know anything about your use case. In most cases you should use the [`Query` component](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-components/#query) to fetch data or [`useQuery`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query) if you are familiar with react hooks.

Comment: @trixn thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. I used the useQuery hook instead of HOC and it has a onCompleted callback that i can use to trigger event after it has, well completed :P. it also doesn't mount my component twice like the HOC. rock on!